# CSS 3 Column Layout with Overflow to next Row

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

Is it possible somehow to have a fixed-height three column layout (using column-count: 3;) that overflows into a next row. Basically paged-media for HTML.

[image: Overflow of Text from one Row into the next row of 3 fixed-height Columns]

Comment: A simple diagram would be a good addition to this question

Comment: can you make a drawing, or do you already have some code to show?

Comment: No code yet besides the three column standard CSS solution. My problem is with a really long text the column height is very high :-) That's why I want to separate it into several rows. I could do some string manipulation with PHP but maybe there is an easy solution with CSS and Overflow handling.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.    
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

This will give you a multi-column layout. If you want multi-column and also multi-row view, then you can just separate the text into a several parts, and then, place every of this parts on it's own `.newspaper` div. Here is live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/sLfcwtcg/

Comment: OK, that's clear so far. This does the the column layout. But is there a way how this would break into several rows as well?

Answer (score 0):

> I prefer this way for older browsers capabilities :

```css
* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

/*
 * Grid helpers inspired from Twitter Bootstrap
 */
.row { margin: 0 -10px; }
.row:before, .row:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.row:after { clear: both; }.row>div { padding: 0 10px; }

.col4{width:33.333333333333%;float:left;}
```

```html
<h1>Title columns</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col4"> 
  <p>lorem  ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla</p>
  </div> 
    <div class="col4"> 
  <p>lorem  ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla</p>
  </div>
    <div class="col4"> 
  <p>lorem  ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla</p>
  </div>
    <div class="col4"> 
  <p>lorem  ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla</p>
  </div>
    <div class="col4"> 
  <p>lorem  ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla</p>
  </div>
    <div class="col4"> 
  <p>lorem  ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```